# Hive select columns to do a case statement on

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-dynamodb

This will export the data from dynamodb dynamically to s3.

```
-- Load S3 Table with data from DynamoDB
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE s3_table SELECT * FROM dynamodb_table;
```

The problem is that it leaves in a bunch of `\N`. I can write it by hand it will look something like

```
-- Load S3 Table with data from DynamoDB
   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE s3_table SELECT DCS_ID, CASE WHEN MAKE IS NULL THEN "" ELSE MAKE END, CASE WHEN MODEL IS NULL THEN "" ELSE MODEL END FROM dynamodb_table;
```

The problem is selecting the columns to say "When **Column** is NULL Then "" Else **Column** End"

The current output looks like this

```
PORTAL  1.5.1.25.2      2013-08-09 13:45:20.126 2013-08-09 13:45:20.282 \N      \N      \N      \N      \N      \N
```

The desired ouput looks like this

```
PORTAL  1.5.1.25.2      2013-08-13 18:18:24.667 2013-08-13 18:18:24.832
```

Comment: What do you mean by "leaves in a bunch of new lines"?

Comment: @climbage I added the output I am getting currently and the output I get when I run it by hand

Comment: Oh, it's literally leaving in `\N`.  Weird.  Sorry for editing that wrong.  Now I understand the issue

Comment: @climbage It is fine, I would have done the same thing if I was you. I believe it does that for any column that does not have value in it.

Comment: @climbage any idea how to select the column in this statement INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE s3_table SELECT * FROM dynamodb_table;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hive output contains the string "\N" for null values (to distinguish from blank), so either you have to prepare each column, or process the output afterwards (could use a stream job if large amounts of data.)

I often use the `coalesce` function for this: `coalesce` takes multiple arguments and returns the first non-null (or null if all null). In your example to avoid the nulls in output, you could do the following:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE s3_table
SELECT coalesce(DCS_ID,''), coalesce(MAKE,''), coalesce(MODEL,'') 
FROM dynamodb_table;
```

Comment: That is interesting! Thanks for the heads up, I will have to explore streaming the job and possibly look into using coalesce, I was just trying to avoid typing out all of the names by hand for each table I have